# How to add a UPI payment option to react native app

Tags: react-native

I had been looking for this many days and didn't get a valid solution. Share some resources if possible.
I am looking for something given in the screen shot below.

**Also**, how can I get back to my app after payment is done from the UPI application, for example Google Pay.
Thank you.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-native-upi-payment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-upi-payment) can be used.
Check out this example https://link.medium.com/1lpojmZxNR

Comment: Have you tested it on ios